# How to delete DevExpress controls in toolbox?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, devexpress

I am using VS 2010. I installed DevExpress Winforms controls a month ago. Today I saw a newer version so I un-installed the one installed. But when I opened VS 2010 the toolbox still has the controls showing. I tried to reset the toolbox but still the controls are showing in-spite of me uninstalling the control suite. My OS is Windows 10.

What do I do to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting them all
 [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238594(v=vs.60).aspx) is the page of microsoft.
and then install the newest version again

Comment: Thank you but it is a temporary fix. If you go to choose toolbox items you will see all the DexExpress controls listed there. Thus it means the entries are still there. Isn't there a better solution?

Comment: Any help will be appreciated.